# Exporting a SwiftUI View as a PNG Image

Tags: swift, swiftui, png

How can I preserve the transparency of a SwiftUI View's background when saving it to Photos using `ImageRenderer`? Currently, when I use the code snippet below, the transparent background of the saved image is displayed as white in the Photos app:

```
guard let image = ImageRenderer(content: MyView).uiImage else {
 // Export failed
 return
}

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

I have noticed that the format of the images being saved is JPEG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pngData()`.

Save as png like this:

```
guard let image = ImageRenderer(content: MyView).uiImage else {
 // Export failed
 return
}

let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .picturesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]         
            
if let data = image.pngData() {
    let fileurl = url.appendingPathComponent("image1.png")
    try? data.write(to: fileurl)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save the PNG image to photos afterwards, I used the PHPhotoLibrary:

```
// Convert the SwiftUI View into an UI Image
guard let image = ImageRenderer(content: MyView).uiImage else {
    // Export failed
    return
}

// Convert UI Image into a PNG image
if let data = image.pngData() {
    // Save PNG image to Photos
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
        creationRequest.addResource(with: .photo, data: data, options: nil)
    }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        if success {
            // Image saved to the Photos app
        } else {
            // Saving image failed
        }
    })
}
```